# Iterate through a dictionary and get the oldest value of a datetime list

Tags: python, dictionary, aws-lambda

I have a Dictionary in Python carrying an `id` and a `date`, something like

```
{'snap-c8': '2015/12/02',
 'snap-23': '2015/12/05',
 'snap-60': '2015/12/06',
 'snap-1a': '2015/12/07',
 'snap-d1': '2015/12/04',
 'snap-67': '2015/12/03',
 'snap-b9': '2015/12/08'}
```

I don't know Python and I need help to create a function that would get me the `snap-` value from the oldest date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) with [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) as a key function:

```
>>> d = {'snap-c8': '2015/12/02', ..., 'snap-b9': '2015/12/08'}
>>> min(d, key=d.get)
'snap-c8'
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfect. If I reverse the dict, putting the date before the snapid, like `'2015/12/02': 'snap-c8'` How would I use `min` function?

Comment: You can do: `d[min(d)]` => `min(d)` to get the oldest date (key), `d[min(d)]` to get the value related to the key.

Comment: Disregard my reverse thing, now I also want to get the date from that snapId, what should I do?

Comment: @Casper, You can use the key you've got: `d[min(d, key=d.get)]`  or  use min directly with values: `min(d.values())`